# .net: How to enforce some limitations on Generics?

Tags: .net, generics, types

Is it possible enforcing some limitations on Type T in Generics?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. What sort of limits would you want to enforce? Would want the enforcement done at compile time or run time?

Comment: He is referring to generic type constraints I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can put some constraints on T. The constraints are introduced with `where` clause. Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

```
where T: struct
```

The type argument must be a value type. Any value type except Nullable can be specified. See Using Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide) for more information.

```
where T: class
```

The type argument must be a reference type; this applies also to any class, interface, delegate, or array type.

```
where T : new()
```

The type argument must have a public parameterless constructor. When used together with other constraints, the new() constraint must be specified last.

```
where T : <base class name>
```

The type argument must be or derive from the specified base class.

```
where T : <interface name>
```

The type argument must be or implement the specified interface. Multiple interface constraints can be specified. The constraining interface can also be generic.

```
where T : U
```

The type argument supplied for T must be or derive from the argument supplied for U.

Comment: I'd be careful with your use of angle brackets there -- in your base class and interface name examples :)

Comment: @Tim Barrass You're right, the will have to be replaced `<base class name>` => `MyClass`

Answer (score 3):

Basically

```
public class MyClass<T> where T : ISomeInterface
```

for example. Lots of existing SO questions too, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886527/generics-with-constraints-hierarchy) for extra detail.

Answer (score 2):

Please see generic parameter [constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx). When creating your own generic types and methods, constraints allow you to apply some rules concerning the type parameters e.g. that they support required interfaces or have a default constructor.